# Use nn.transformerEncoder for context-free grammar parsing (sequence classification)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, nlp, transformer-model

I want to use a transformer to do context-free grammar parsing (to classify whether a sequence is in the grammar or not). The input are sequences like "abbaba", the output is 0 or 1. Here's my transformer architecture:

```
class PositionalEncoding(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, d_model, max_len=200, dropout=0.1):
        super().__init__()
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=dropout)

        pe = torch.zeros(max_len, d_model)
        position = torch.arange(0, max_len, dtype=torch.float).unsqueeze(1)
        div_term = torch.exp(
            torch.arange(0, d_model, 2).float()
            * (-math.log(10000.0) / d_model)
        )
        pe[:, 0::2] = torch.sin(position * div_term)
        pe[:, 1::2] = torch.cos(position * div_term)
        pe = pe.unsqueeze(0)
        self.register_buffer("pe", pe)

    def forward(self, x):
        # print(self.pe.shape, x.shape)
        x = x + self.pe[:, : x.size(1), :]
        return self.dropout(x)


class TransformerClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, d_model, num_classes, num_layers, nhead, dim_feedforward, dropout):
        super(TransformerClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.d_model = d_model
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(input_size, d_model)

        self.encoder_layer = nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(d_model=d_model, nhead=nhead, dim_feedforward=dim_feedforward, dropout=dropout)

        self.transformer_encoder = nn.TransformerEncoder(self.encoder_layer, num_layers=num_layers)

        self.pos_encoder = PositionalEncoding(d_model=d_model, dropout=dropout)
        
        self.linear = nn.Linear(d_model, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.embedding(x) * math.sqrt(self.d_model)
        x = self.pos_encoder(x)
        x = self.transformer_encoder(x)
        x = x.mean(dim=1)  # Aggregate across the sequence dimension
        x = self.linear(x)
        return x
```

I set the hyperparameters to:

```
input_size = 27 # 26 letters + <pad>
d_model = 50
dim_feedforward = 50
nhead = 5
num_classes = 2  # Binary classification (0 or 1)
num_layers = 4
dropout = 0.1
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
```

The lr was set to 1e-4, batch size was 20.
The training loop:

```
epochs = 100
epoch_losses = []
for epoch in range(epochs):
    batch_loss = []
    for inputs, targets in tqdm(train_dataloader):
        inputs = inputs.to(device)
        targets = targets.to(device)
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(inputs)
        loss = criterion(outputs, targets)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        batch_loss.append(loss.item())

    epoch_loss = sum(batch_loss) / len(batch_loss)
    epoch_losses.append(sum(batch_loss) / len(batch_loss))
    print(f"Epoch [{epoch+1}/{epochs}], Loss: {epoch_loss:.4f}")
```

However the result seems to be abnormal.
The training curve seems to be a bit noisy:

Also, even if I use a very large transformer (large values for d_model, nhead, num_layer, etc), the accuracy on the training set is about 0.7-0.8 and don't go higher. Also, sometimes the accuracy on the test set was even higher than the training set. Additionally, I want to test how the transformer perform on OOD data (I set OOD here to be longer sequences, and only train the model with shorter sequences), I found that the accuracy on OOD test set was sometimes higher than ID (in distribution) test set, and sometimes even higher than training set.

I was very confused and was wondering what's wrong.

I want to know if there's anything wrong with my codes or are there any other mistakes.

Comment: What loss function are you using?

Comment: nn.CrossEntropyLoss, and the optimizer is adam